# Optimize SQL Query or archive the large table

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I'm trying to optimize my SQL Query because it takes 12s - 15s to execute and it will show only 3 rows.

This is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    [bs].[id] AS 'id'
  , [pt].[parenttask] AS 'parent'
  , [ct].[childtaskname] AS 'child'
  , [tc].[TaskCategoryName] AS 'taskCat'
  , [bs].[volume] AS 'volume'
  , FORMAT([bs].[startTime], 'hh:mm:ss tt') AS 'startTime'
  , FORMAT([bs].[endtime], 'hh:mm:ss tt') AS 'endTime'
  , [bs].[ReportingDate] AS 'reportDate'
  , [ts].[taskstatusname] AS 'taskStatus'
  , [bs].[TotalTAT] AS 'tat'
  , [ta].[TaskOwnerWorkdayID] 'workdayId'
  , [pt].[teamID] 'teamId'
  , [ts].[id] 'tasksStat'
FROM [tbl_DiloBillableServices] [bs] WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN [tbl_taskallocation] [ta] WITH(NOLOCK)
     ON [ta].[ID] = [bs].[TaskAllocationID]
INNER JOIN [tbl_sostasks] [pt] WITH(NOLOCK)
     ON [pt].[id] = [ta].[parenttaskID]
INNER JOIN [tbl_soschildtasks] [ct] WITH(NOLOCK)
     ON [ct].[id] = [ta].[ChildtaskID]
INNER JOIN [tbl_taskcategory] [tc] WITH(NOLOCK)
     ON [tc].[id] = [ta].[TaskCategoryID]
INNER JOIN [tbl_tasksstatus] [ts] WITH(NOLOCK)
     ON [ts].[id] = [bs].[taskstatusID]
WHERE [ta].[taskownerworkdayid] = 388537
      AND [bs].[reportingdate] = '2/13/2020'
      AND [pt].[teamID] = 68
      AND [bs].[taskstatusID] <> 5;
```

This is all the list of table that I've used above :

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_DiloBillableServices
```

> Running time: 6s Records: 300000 +

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_taskallocation
```

> Running time: 3s Records: 170000 +

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_sostasks
```

> Running time: 0 Records: 10000 +

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_soschildtasks
```

> Running time: 0 Records: 10000 +

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_taskcategory
```

> Running time: 0 Records: 5 +

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_tasksstatus
```

> Running time: 0 Records: 5 +

Is there any ways to optimize that query above? or I should archive the 2 tables above with the oldest data?

If that the case that I should archive the data, what is the better way to do that?

Comment: Can you share the actual execution plan?  https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: There isn't a huge amount of data in your tables, it seems premature to be thinking of archiving. Are the primary keys set up as I'd expect, eg is ID the single PK on the table tbl_taskallocation, is it an int and is used as the clustering index? Is this true of the tables you're joining to?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Done.

Comment: For starters I would suggest getting rid of those NOLOCKS. They are NOT a performance tool that come without some very serious side affects. https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere Also when using string literals for dates you should always use the ANSI compliant YYYYMMDD. This will always correctly be interpreted regardless of language settings.

Comment: You said you have posted the plan, where is it?

Comment: Thanks for the info @SeanLange, noted for that.

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJi1kkQX8 here it is.

Comment: You don t have any index in your tables and they make table scan. It means that the query optimizer read all rows of the table and it is not selective.  This condition hurts your performance add least you can create the advised indexes.

Comment: `CREATE INDEX workday_ID ON tbl_taskallocation (taskownerworkdayid)` something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss indexes. Add an index on tbl_taskallocation(taskownerworkdayid) will greatly improve the performance. Index on tbl_DiloBillableServices will also help.

Comment: `CREATE INDEX workday_ID ON tbl_taskallocation (taskownerworkdayid)` this one?

Comment: yes, follow the naming convention your organization has